# Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I have this Model :

```
public function getmstasset($id)
{
    //$this->load->model('sitemodel');
    //$data['content']=$this->sitemodel->listpelanggan()->result_array();

    $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', true);
    return $this->db1->select('assetview.*')
                    ->from('assetview')
                    ->where('idasset',$id)
                    ->get();
    //$this->load->view('template', $data, FALSE);
}
```

Controller :

```
public function addfromasset($id)
{
    $this->load->model('assetmodeltrn');
    $data['getasset'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->getmstasset($id)->result_array(); 
    $data['content'] = 'transaksi/assetdist_trn';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

view :

Mac Address *
                                
                                    mac_addr; ?>" name="macaddr"  readonly="readonly" required="required" type="text">

```
                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="serialnum">Serial Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="serialnum" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="serialnum" value="<? echo $getasset->serialnumber ?>"  readonly="readonly" placeholder="Serial Number" required="required" type="text"></input> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

return error :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: transaksi/assetdist_trn.php

Line Number: 26

Please Help

Best Regards,

Dian

Comment: It's late in the day. My psychic powers are running low. Can you remind me which line is #26, per your error? It'd be much appreciated. Oh, and maybe which code belongs to the file `transaksi/assetdist_trn.php`. And any other relevant information pertaining to *your* issue.

Comment: yes, line #26 in on transaksi/assetdist_trn.php, try to get value for input from model getmstasset. this is the code :  <input id="serialnum" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="serialnum" value="<? echo $getasset->serialnumber ?>"  readonly="readonly" placeholder="Serial Number" required="required" type="text"></input> 
                            </div>

Comment: If that is line 26, then `$getasset` is not an object. But I don't see where you've set `$getasset` in your code so I cannot help you further. Please post all relevant code pertaining to your problem.

Comment: It's on controller,  $this->load->model('assetmodeltrn');
    $data['getasset'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->getmstasset($id)->result_array(); 
    $data['content'] = 'transaksi/assetdist_trn';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I change the controller from :

$data['getasset'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->getmstasset($id)->result_array();

to

$data['getasset'] = $this->assetmodeltrn->getmstasset($id)->row();

Thanks

Dian